# Using Currying and Module.export together in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

/startup/routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const users = require("../routes/users");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use("/api/users", users);
};
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("./startup/routes")(app);
```

I am confused with the code above, especially the currying in "index.js". Can someone explains me how it works? Generally i am doing the same job as below. What is the difference between them?

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
```

Comment: I don't see any currying in `index.js`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I assume it's referring to `require("./startup/routes")(app);`

Comment: @VLAZ - Probably, yeah.

Comment: @jsonkiller - `require("./startup/routes")(app);` - that's called immediately invoked function expression or IIFE ("iffy").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`routes.js` exports a function as its default export. `index.js` imports and runs the function in one expression:

```
require("./startup/routes")(app);
```

That's equivalent to:

```
const routesFunction = require("./startup/routes");
routesFunction(app);
```

---

Re your version without a `routes.js`, it does the same thing the original code does, the only difference is that it's all in one module.

Comment: isn't it currying "require("./startup/routes")(app);"

Comment: @jsonkiller - No, that's just immediately using the function that `require` returns. But curried functions are often called the same way, it's is an easy mistake to make.